# Creating a MySQL database for a Drupal 6 install via a script

Tags: mysql, shell, scripting, drupal-6

I'm trying to automate the creation of new local Drupal 6 installs for module development, etc.

I know how to write bash scripts and have drush installed on my local development environment, but I don't know how to write scripts that will create the necessary MySQL database. Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following query for my auto-create script:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO db_name@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'db_name' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO db_name@127.0.0.1;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The shell command looks like this:

```
echo "$sql" | mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

This is taken from a custom drush command script in PHP but I think will work in a bash script just the same.